# Validating forms data

Tags: php, php5, form, validation

Here is a class that I made to validate forms data.  I will really appreciate any criticism and hints.

```
  <?php

class formvalidator {

    public $filtered, $errors,$db,
    $fields_type = Array(), $error_msgs = Array();

    public function validate($form, $fields, $error_msgs) {

        $this->fields_type = $fields;
        $this->error_msgs = $error_msgs;

        foreach ($form as $field => $data) {

            if (isset($this->fields_type[$field])) {
                if (method_exists($this, $this->fields_type[$field])) {
                    $_POST[$field] = call_user_func_array(array($this, $this->fields_type[$field]), array($data));

                    if ($_POST[$field] === false) {
                        $this->errors[$field] = sprintf($this->error_msgs[$field], $data);
                     }
                }
            } else {//Else ? unset it Security ?
                unset($_POST[$field]);
            }
        }

        //Manual validation for password and password confirmation 
        if($_POST['form'] == 'signup' or $_POST['form'] == 'login')
        if (!isset($_POST['password'])) {
            $this->errors[$field] = sprintf($this->error_msgs['password'], '');
        }
        if (isset($_POST['repassword']) and $_POST['password'] != $_POST['repassword']) {
            $this->errors[$field] = sprintf($this->error_msgs['repassword'], '');
        }
        //End of password confirmation and password check.

        //
        $_POST = $this->clean($_POST);    

        if (is_null($this->errors)) {
            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }

    public function value_calss($input) {
        if (isset($_POST[$input])) {
            if (isset($this->errors[$input])) {
                echo ' error ';
            } else {
                echo '" value = "' . $_POST[$input];
            }
        }
    }

    public function errors() {

        if (!is_null($this->errors)) {
            echo '<div class=" messagebox errorbox"><br><h4>Please Fix these:</h4><br><ul>';
            foreach ($this->errors as $error)
                echo "<li>$error</li>";
            echo '</ul><br></div><br>';
        }
    }

    public function setError($error) {
        $this->errors[] = $error;
    }


    //Validations

    public function IsEmail($email) {
        return filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    }

    public function IsAlphaNum($str) {
        if (ctype_alnum($str))
            return trim($str);
        else
            return false;
    }

    public function IsString($str) {
        if (preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9\s]+[^ ]$/", $str))
            return trim($str);
        else
            return false;
    }

//Explite will return false on empty values which will cause raise error flag.
    public function explite($input) {
        return trim($input);
    }


    public function text($input){
        return trim(htmlentities($input));
    }

    public function IsDate($is_date){ 
        if(strtotime($is_date))
            return date("Y-m-d",strtotime($is_date));
        else
            return false;
    }

    public function file($input)
    {
        return $input;
    }

    public function boolen($input)
    {
        if($input)
            return true;
        else false;
    }


    public function clean($input) {
        $clean = Array();
        foreach ($input as $field => $data) {
            $clean[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
        }
        return $clean;
    }




}

?>
```

Update: [New Version on gist](https://gist.github.com/2011557)

Comment: Comment to self: Rename `valure_class()` method with `attributes()` as it either returns class or value.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that I see right off the bat, is the `clean()` method.  Why are you escaping things arbitrarily?

```
public function clean($input) {
    $clean = Array();
    foreach ($input as $field => $data) {
        $clean[$field] = mysql_real_escape_string($data);
    }
    return $clean;
}
```

All you're doing is making it harder to trace code, and harder to prove if your code is secure or not.  Not to mention that's a *major* breach of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

It's a huge side-effect and should be removed.

Always escape or quote as close as possible to where you're putting it.